# Javascript,if condition works without && logical operator when && is present it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, logical-operators

I want the *error* message to *display* if the *length* of characters in the `#nameT` `id` is less than `<` 3 or greater `<`than 20.When I use `&&` *logical operator* it doesn't work as intended when `&&` is absent if I execute the code one by one it works perfectly.

```
<style>
    .name{
        border: .5px solid #C0C0C0;
        margin-left: 1em;
        margin-right: 1em;
        padding: .7em;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    #error{
        display: inline-block;
        color: #727171;
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding: .5em;
        margin-top: .5em;
        display:none;
    }

    label{
        color:grey;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <label>Name :<input class="name" id ="nameT" onblur="check()" type="text"></input></label>

    <div id="error">Error please type less than 15 characters</div><br/>

    <label>Password :<input class="name" type="password"></input></label>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function check() {
    var length = document.getElementById("nameT").value.length;
    var error = document.getElementById("error");

    if(length < 20 && length < 3){
        error.style.display="inline-block";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You say greater than 20 OR smaller than 3. You dont need && (AND) but || (OR) for that

Comment: ofcourse if you want to check if the value is between 20 and 3 you can use `length > 3 && length < 20`

Comment: @Thalsan it error appeards if its `less` that 3 but no `<` than 20 and sorry I was wrong with the question.

Comment: @Thalsan I want to display and error if the `length` is `less` than `3` or `greater` than `20` .

Comment: you are right, then my last comment is wrong. I would suggest using `if (length < 3 || length > 20)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No value of `length` can be at the same time greater than 20 and less than 3.

I think what you are trying to do is to set the error display of the length is more than 20 or less than 3, if so you need to use OR(||) logical operator

```
if(length > 20 || length < 3){
    error.style.display="inline-block";
}
```

when you use `AND` operator, both the operands has to be true only then the logical operator will return true. In your case that is simply impossible.

Comment: hey I edited my code take a look at it,I changed it to `< 3 && < 20`

Comment: I want to display and error if the `length` is `less` than `3` or `greater` than `20` .

Comment: Thank you you help me everytime,I am also from bangalore.Everytime I see you and I envy you for ur knowledge,oneday I wanna be like you a expert..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `||` (or) operator. Your current `if` branch will only be entered when length is bigger than 20 *and at the same time* smaller than 3, which, as you can see, can never happen.

```
if (length > 20 || length < 3) {
    ...
```